# calculating distance did not give the right answer using php because the answers are not real

Tags: php, distance

can anyone tell me if the formula of calculating distance using longitude and latitude is correct??

like the distance between 2 cities as the formula show is more than 135 km and this is not realll

## code.php

```
      <?php 

    $result="";
          if(isset($_POST['calculate'], $_POST['pt1'], $_POST['pt2']))
            {
                $pt1 = $_POST['pt1'];
                $pt2 = $_POST['pt2'];

                $points = array();

                $sql = mysql_query("SELECT longitude, lattitude, village_name FROM village WHERE id = '$pt1' OR id = '$pt2'")or die(mysql_error()); // See how I added the village name column !
                $num_row = mysql_num_rows($sql);
                if($num_row > 0)
                {
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
                    {
                        $points[] = array($row['longitude'], $row['lattitude'], $row['village_name']); // add point to array , [also adding the village_name]
                    }
                }
                if(count($points) == 2){ // Check if there are 2 points
                        $PI = acos(-1);
                        $lon_s = $points[0][0];
                        $lon_s = ($lon_s/180)*$PI;

                        $lat_s = $points[0][1];
                        $lat_s = ($lat_s/180)*$PI; 

                        $lon_e = $points[1][0];
                        $lon_e = ($lon_e/180)*$PI;

                        $lat_e = $points[1][1];
                        $lat_e = ($lat_s/180)*$PI;

                        $R = 6371; //km
                        $A = pow(sin(($lat_e - $lat_s)/2), 2) + cos($lat_s) * cos($lat_e) * pow(sin(($lon_e - $lon_s)/2) , 2);
                        $C = 2 * atan2(sqrt($A), sqrt(1 - $A));
                        $D = $R * $C;

                    $result= 'The distance between <br/>'. $points[0][2] . ' and '. $points[1][2].' <br /> is <br/>'. $D .'&nbsp;'.'km'; // Let's output something fancy
                }
            }
?>
```

because it give a distance not related to the reality i talk about a small country

Comment: I've made the same formula in MySQL - maybe it will help you: [Applying Information from one table to a separate table in same database?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15512707)

Comment: so is the formula right ??? because i need to have it in php

Comment: Obviously it isn't right if it's giving you distances that are way too large...

Comment: but i check the formula in other sites it is the same [http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/haversine/]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you might be working directly with the latitude and longitude degree values without converting them into radians, which is needed by the sin() and cos() functions, for instance. It is possible that simply converting them would solve the issue for you, inside your formula:

```
$PI = acos(-1);
$lat_e = ($lat_e/180) * $PI;
$lat_s = ($lat_s/180) * $PI;
$lon ...
```

Alternatively, an easy way to calculate 3D coordinates from the latitude and longitude is to use the following formula:

```
$x = sin($lon/180*$PI)*cos($lat/180*$PI)*$alt;
$y = cos($lon/180*$PI)*cos($lat/180*$PI)*$alt;
$z = sin($lat/180*$PI)*$alt;
```

It looks like you are ignoring the altitude of the cities, so you can just omit `$alt`. From here, you can simply apply basic distance between two 3D points, and multiply it by the Earth radius, in this case 6371:

```
$x = ($x - $x2) * ($x - $x2);
$y = ($y - $y2) * ($y - $y2);
$z = ($z - $z2) * ($z - $z2);
$D = sqrt($x + $y + $z) * $R;
```

Note I avoided `pow()` merely for performance reasons.

Comment: so in my code this will be the formula ???? **$lon_s = $points[0][0];
$lon_s = $lon_s/180*PI;
                    
$lat_s = $points[0][1];
$lat_s = $lat_s/180*PI; 
$lon_e = $points[1][0];
$lon_e = $lon_e/180*PI;
$lat_e = $points[1][1];
$lat_e = $lat_s/180*PI;
     
                    $R = 6371; //km
                    $A = pow(sin(($lat_e - $lat_s)/2), 2) + cos($lat_s) * cos($lat_e) * pow(sin(($lon_e - $lon_s)/2) , 2);
                    $C = 2 * atan2(sqrt($A), sqrt(1 - $A));
                    $D = $R * $C;**

Comment: i add as you said  but the browser display this error   **Use of undefined constant PI - assumed 'PI**

Comment: I forgot the $, just edited the code. Try again :) `$PI = acos(-1)`. Also, you can do the conversion directly as in `$lon_s = $points[0][0]/180 * $PI`, but i can't guarantee it is correct since I do not know the contents of $points, I just assume you have degrees in there.

Comment: it is also not correct it give me this result **3665.4177862968 km**

Comment: That begs the question, what are the actual values of latitudes and longitudes you are using?

Comment: @user2394498 This is in degrees, which means you DO have to convert it to radians through X/180*PI. This formula gives correct values for me. By the way, i asked for the actual values as in all 4 values so that I can check the correct distance you are looking for.

Comment: pt1  **latitude:33.862893**  **longitude:35.517571**                        pt2  **latitude:33.887386**  **longitude: 35.520906**

Comment: I get 2.740845 km with both your and my formula. Your formula gives the correct answer, you need to check if your input values are actually correct in the variables $lon_s, $lat_s, $lon_e and $lat_e, just after retrieving them.

Comment: these are the long and lat for the first point in the database ..**lat=33.526987 long=35.388799**   second **lat=33.771408 long = 35.529833**  after retrieving and divide 180 and multiply by PI  for the **lat1 = 0.61765106087648 lon1 = 0.58515631142334 lat2 = 0.62011256853373 lon2 = 0.010212904273163**  can anyone tel me what he have as result ??

Comment: You have a copy-paste error in `$lat_e = ($lat_s/180)*$PI;` (it should be $lat_e/180). Also you're switching up latitudes and longitudes. The values should be `lat1 = 0.585156` `lon1 = 0.617651` `lat2 = 0.589422` `lon2 = 0.620113` and the final answer is 30.151069km

Comment: i did change the error but now i get for the same 2 points that i send  it to you the result is **5.0123965196217 km**

Comment: Then your error must be somewhere else, because the code you showed above for your formula gives the correct results when given correct values for $lon_s, $lat_s, $lon_e and $lat_e, and the formula works fine here.

Comment: i asked a new question if you can help me ??[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616516/display-picture-within-the-popup-window-on-the-google-map]

Answer (score 0):

also check if `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))` is giving proper results. try

```
`$result=mrsql_query($sql);`$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
```

Comment: what is the difference between what you wrote and what i did ?? because i did the same i did the mysql _query and the fetch _array

Comment: you used mysql_fetch_array($sql) on $sql.

Comment: i meann what is the difference between the $result and the $sql if i did the mysql_fetch _array on $sql?? i am not telling you that is not correct i am just asking you

Comment: you are using _fetch_array() on query directly. and i am asking you to check result on mysql_query then use fetch_array() on that result.check both output for better understandings